# Algorithm to merge two objects the most efficiently

Tags: java

I have a class `Level1` that contains a `String` and a list of `Level2` objects. The `Level2` objects each contain a `String` and a list of `Level3` objects. The `Level3` objects each contain 2 String attributes, `attribute1` and `attribute2`. (This is similar to a a 3 level tree)

Now I have two objects of class `Level1` : `objectA` and `objectB`.

`objectB` is included in `objectA`. All the branches within B will have a match in A).

`objectA` leaves will have `attribute1`. `objectB` will have `attribute2`.

I want to most efficient way to merge `objectA` to `objectB`. By merge I mean the new object will have all the branches and attributes of `objectA` and the attributes of `objectB` where corresponding. All nodes are unique.

A dummy algorithm would have a `O(n^2)` complexity, which is not good for my purpose. Because of the tree I'm hoping there is a `O(n log n)` but I can't find it

Thanks!

Class for Level1:

```
public class Level1 {

    private String level1string;

    private List<Level2> level2List;

    public String getLevel1string() {
        return level1string;
    }

    public void setLevel1string(String level1string) {
        this.level1string = level1string;
    }

    public List<Level2> getLevel2List() {
        return level2List;
    }

    public void setLevel2List(List<Level2> level2List) {
        this.level2List = level2List;
    }
}
```

Class for Level2:

```
public class Level2 {
    private String level2string;

    private List<Level3> level3List;

    public String getLevel2string() {
        return level2string;
    }

    public void setLevel2string(String level2string) {
        this.level2string = level2string;
    }

    public List<Level3> getLevel3List() {
        return level3List;
    }

    public void setLevel3List(List<Level3> level3List) {
        this.level3List = level3List;
    }
}
```

Class for Level3:

```
public class Level3 {

    private String attribute1;

    public String getAttribute1() {
        return attribute1;
    }

    public void setAttribute1(String attribute1) {
        this.attribute1 = attribute1;
    }

    public String getAttribute2() {
        return attribute2;
    }

    public void setAttribute2(String attribute2) {
        this.attribute2 = attribute2;
    }

    private String attribute2;
}
```

Here are two sample elements level1_A and level1_B

```
public class constructobjects {

    private Level3 level3_A1 = new Level3();
    private Level3 level3_A2 = new Level3();
    private Level3 level3_A3 = new Level3();
    private Level3 level3_A4 = new Level3();
    private Level3 level3_A5 = new Level3();
    private Level3 level3_A6 = new Level3();
    private Level3 level3_A7 = new Level3();
    private Level3 level3_A8 = new Level3();

    private Level2 level2_A1 = new Level2();
    private Level2 level2_A2 = new Level2();
    private Level2 level2_A3 = new Level2();

    private Level1 level1_A = new Level1();

    public void constructObjectA(){
        level3_A1.setAttribute1("sampleAttribute1");
        level3_A2.setAttribute1("sampleAttribute2");
        level3_A3.setAttribute1("sampleAttribute3");
        level3_A4.setAttribute1("sampleAttribute4");
        level3_A5.setAttribute1("sampleAttribute5");
        level3_A6.setAttribute1("sampleAttribute6");
        level3_A7.setAttribute1("sampleAttribute7");
        level3_A8.setAttribute1("sampleAttribute8");

        List<Level3> level3List_A1 = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Level3> level3List_A2 = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Level3> level3List_A3 = new ArrayList<>();

        level3List_A1.add(level3_A1);
        level3List_A1.add(level3_A2);
        level3List_A1.add(level3_A3);

        level3List_A2.add(level3_A4);
        level3List_A2.add(level3_A5);
        level3List_A2.add(level3_A6);

        level3List_A3.add(level3_A7);
        level3List_A3.add(level3_A8);

        level2_A1.setLevel3List(level3List_A1);
        level2_A2.setLevel3List(level3List_A2);
        level2_A3.setLevel3List(level3List_A3);

        level2_A1.setLevel2string("sampleLevel2String_foo");
        level2_A2.setLevel2string("sampleLevel2String_bar");
        level2_A3.setLevel2string("sampleLevel2String_chi");

        List<Level2> level2List_A1 = new ArrayList<>();

        level2List_A1.add(level2_A1);
        level2List_A1.add(level2_A2);
        level2List_A1.add(level2_A3);

        level1_A.setLevel2List(level2List_A1);
        level1_A.setLevel1string("root");


    }



    private Level3 level3_B1 = new Level3();

    private Level3 level3_B3 = new Level3();

    private Level3 level3_B8 = new Level3();

    private Level2 level2_B1 = new Level2();
    private Level2 level2_B3 = new Level2();

    private Level1 level1_B = new Level1();

    public void constructObjectB(){
        level3_B1.setAttribute2("otherAttribute1");
        level3_B3.setAttribute2("otherAttribute3");
        level3_B8.setAttribute2("otherAttribute8");

        List<Level3> level3List_B1 = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Level3> level3List_B3 = new ArrayList<>();

        level3List_B1.add(level3_B1);
        level3List_B1.add(level3_B3);
        level3List_B3.add(level3_B8);

        level2_B1.setLevel3List(level3List_B1);
        level2_B3.setLevel3List(level3List_B3);

        level2_B1.setLevel2string("sampleLevel2String_foo");
        level2_B3.setLevel2string("sampleLevel2String_chi");

        List<Level2> level2List_B1 = new ArrayList<>();

        level2List_B1.add(level2_B1);
        level2List_B1.add(level2_B3);

        level1_B.setLevel2List(level2List_B1);
        level1_B.setLevel1string("root");


    }

}
```

Comment: This might be easier to understand if you had a code sample or interface description of the different object types...

Comment: I just added the classes for you, let me know if you need anything else

Comment: I don't think it will be useful, it is exactly as you said with no additional logic. Maybe you should show us how you construct `objectA` and `objectB` to make it clear.

Comment: You could try to merge the different levels in parallel in different threads if your structure is thread safe. That is, merge level1 and launch 2 threads in order to merge level2. The result of the threads can be used to build the final object.

Comment: @dici: And I Could create two dummy objectA and objectB and the result of merge(objectA,objectB) and you would say the same?

Comment: There are well known APIs for doing this in Java (ser concurrent package)

Comment: @Victor parallel programming does not affect complexity (as far as I know). He first must to improve his algorithm and then see if it can be multi-threaded.

Comment: @Stephane I don't get your question. What I meant is that it would be nice that you show us what "B is included in A" means by constructing two instances that match that condition

Comment: @Dici ok I'm building a sample right now

Comment: @Dici, you are right. However it seems to me that this problem forces you to visit each node in each tree and unless you use a structure that links the three leaves and allows you to begin from the bottom of the three, it will be hard to reduce complexity.

Comment: the idea I had but I don't know how to implement it is to "get rid" of a part of ObjectB once matched or not matched, so you don't do duplicate visits

Comment: @Dici I have created two dummy objects. If you draw them on a piece of paper you should see how they merge. Let me know

Comment: @Stephane Wow that's quite a long piece of code ! Thanks for the example, let me study it

Comment: @Stephane ok I get it. For the algorithm to be efficient, I think the nodes have to be sorted or stored in a data structure that allows a fast retrieval (such as `HashSet`) so that the cost of finding corresponding nodes in `A` and `B` is low

Comment: makes sense. How to construct a HashSet on a tree though?

Comment: I would simply use the `HashSet` instead of your `ArrayList`s.

Comment: with keys<String,String<LevelX>> ?

Comment: I'm writing an attempt of answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it is exactly what you want, but as far as I'm concerned I would use hash maps instead of array lists. For the `LevelX` instances to be usable in a `HashMap`, you will need to override `hashCode` and `equals` methods.

For example in `Level1` :

```
Map<String,Level2> children = new HashMap<>();
final String name;

public Level1(String name) {
    // add to the pool or use the existing reference to 
    // avoid duplicating information
    this.name = name.intern();
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (o == null) return false;
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
    Level1 other = (Level1) o;
    // assuming name is never null
    return other.name.equals(name);
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return level1String.hashCode();
}
```

Then, the merge method would simply have to merge the hashsets and complexity would be O(n + m) where n (resp. m) is the number of nodes in A (resp. B).

```
// I assume other is "contained" in this
public Level1 merge(Level1 other) {
    Level1 result = new Level1("root");
    for (Level2 child : other.children) {
        // cannot be null if other is contained in this
        Level2 corresponding = children.get(child.name);
        corresponding.children.putAll(child.children);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks! this is the first time I see HashSet so I'm still catching up on the code. How would you invoke the merge function?

Comment: In fact, I'm think a `HashMap` would be better, `HashSet` can only help us merging without duplicates and for contain tests but not for retrieval.

Comment: Yep. But a Hashmap would "duplicate" string information (which is not so bad).

Comment: @Stephane Right ! However you can enter your strings in the pool so that all instances of strings containing the same characters will point to a unique reference, and thus save memory. I'm writing a merge right now